# Corollary of Green's Identities/Formulas

Tags: calculus

Green's Identities in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are as follows
\begin{align}
\int_\Sigma (\nabla f \cdot \nabla g + f \Delta g) \, dV &= \int_{\mathcal{S}} f \nabla g \cdot \mathbf N \, d \mathcal{A}\\
\int_\Sigma (f \Delta g - g \Delta f) \, dV &= \int_{\mathcal{S}} (f \nabla g - g \nabla f) \cdot \mathbf N \, d \mathcal{A}\\
\end{align}

With $f, g $ scalar fields, $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathcal{S}$ its smooth boundary surface, $\mathbf N$ the unit normal vector, and $\nabla, \Delta$ the gradient, Laplacian, respectively. It follows from Divergence theorem, with $\mathbf F = f \nabla g$.

As a corollary, I have to prove the following:

$$\Delta f = 0 \text{ in } \Sigma \text { and } \nabla g \perp \mathbf N \text{ on } \mathcal{S} \Rightarrow \int_\Sigma \nabla f \cdot \nabla g \, dV = 0$$

$$\Delta f = 0 \text{ in } \Sigma \text{ and } \nabla f  \perp \mathbf N \text{ on } \mathcal{S} \Rightarrow f = 0 \text{ in } \Sigma$$

The second is related to the first by taking $f = g$. We get $\int_\Sigma \| \nabla f \|^2$ which, as pointed out in a current answer, implies $\nabla f = 0$.

I've tried a bunch of algebraic manipulations to get  the first statement but I can't. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you certain that you have these conditions correct? At least one of the two seems dubious.

Comment: @Dr.MV other students in this class remarked that the conditions in the first statement may be incorrect (and we must have $\nabla f \perp N$ not $\nabla g \perp N$), and in that case the statement is quite obvious. Also, personally for the second I don't see how to prove $f = 0$ from $\nabla f = 0$.

Comment: $f$ can be any constant if $\nabla f=0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Indeed, which is where my confusion lies. This professor has not been immune to typos in the past, so it is certainly possible we are being led on a wild goose chase here.

Comment: That is likely.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you get
$\int_\Sigma \|\nabla f\|^2 \, dV=0$?

This yields that $\nabla f=0$ on the whole $\Sigma$. By the Mean Value Theorem [in several variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables), this implies that $f$ is locally constant.

If $\Sigma$ is connected, this proves that $f$ is constant on $\Sigma$ hence, up to a constant, $0$.

Comment: Oh yeah, you're completely right. I accidentally had $\nabla f \cdot \nabla f = \Delta f$ rather then $\nabla f \cdot \nabla f = \|\nabla f \|^2$. Can you elaborate on the connectedness of the domain?

Comment: Right away, give me $5$ minutes. @Soke

Comment: Is it actually legitimate to say that $f$ is constant and thus, up to a constant, it is $0$? I get that it's true but I feel like we're cheating if we say that because the notion of constant and zero are different, no?

Comment: You are right: it is cheating, and maybe you are dealing with a problem where this is relevant. In that case, the result that holds is that $f$ is constant (notice that a constant has $\Delta c\equiv0$, $\nabla c\equiv0$). @Soke

I thought, looking at the statement, that you were in a context where either constants were irrelevant (for instance, electromagnetic potential or explicit prior declaration) or where this was obvious (some implicit request of vector fields to vanish at infinity, or even to have compact support). Sorry for my lack of punctuality.

Comment: Don't worry. I think the problem may just be a fault on the behalf of my professor.